# If using a switch that supports VLAN can some devices connect directly to the router?

Tags: networking, home-networking, vlan

Typical home network - a few pcs, smartphones and IP cameras. I have 2 pcs that I want to isolate from being able to access or see the traffic of other devices on the network.

I have acquired a [Netgear 8 port "smart" switch](https://www.netgear.com/business/wired/switches/smart/gs308t/)

If I set up a VLAN within the switch to put those two pcs on, do I need to set up another VLAN to put the other devices on? If so, won't I also need a wireless access point to plug into the switch for the other devices? Or, can I connect directly to the router for those devices?

eg.  Setup I'm wondering about
[image]

Comment: Are you asking about connecting to the router specifically via Wi-Fi? What kind of router do you currently have, and does it have VLAN support? Are the two PCs supposed to have _Internet_ access but not LAN, or no network access at all?

Comment: Additionally, your router needs to keep the vlans separate as well. If you're using separate subnets for each VLAN, then it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: The wireless AP question depends on what your APs are capable of - you can often isolate specific devices right there by mac address, or create a second wlan with its own SSID to use. If you get fancier stuff, then you can tag vlan traffic per-device/ssid/subnet on an AP as well

Comment: I dont think my router supports setting up VLAN's the way a switch does.  Ive added a diagram above to show what I had in mind. and added more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PCs 1 and 2 are supposed to access the router (the internet) but not the other devices your router needs to support this (eg via a guest network on one of the LAN ports etc.).

If it doesn't you need to set up a firewall (or flash your router with an OS that does, e.g. DD-WRT). You **can not** separate networks **AND** distribute internet access just with VLAN.

If PCs 1 and 2 don't need internet access just disconnect the router from the switch.

**Update:** If you only have a WiFi guest network, you can access it via one of the two PCs (e.g. via a cheap WiFi USB adapter) and share it with the other one. Or put some other device on the same VLAN that accesses the guest network and can share it with the PCs.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what your saying.  Yes, my router (Linksys EA7300) supports a guest network, but only for wifi.

Comment: @bitshift see update, also, Linksys will probably support DD-WRT

Comment: If I were to look for another router that has better VLAN support for the above scenario, what are some models to look at.  ASUS for example doesn’t support VLAN for LAN supposedly, at least not with consumer-grade routers.

Comment: I know that some FritzBox routers support guest LAN on Ethernet other than that I'm not sure about other consumer routers. But as I said you'll need a firewall, not a router.